# Is this the wrong way to find $\delta$?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Find $\delta$ such that $$|x^n - a^n| < \epsilon $$ whenever $$|x-a|<\delta$$

My thought is factoring $|x^n-a^n|$ so we have $|(x-a)|\cdot|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}|$

In order to make it smaller than $\epsilon$, I let $|x-a|<1$, so I have $$(a-1)^k<x^k<(a+1)^k$$

Thus,

$$|(x-a)|\cdot |(a-1)^{n-1}+(a-1)^{n-2}a+..+a^{n-1}| <|(x-a)|\cdot|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}| \hspace{0.5cm} (1)$$

so I choose $$\delta=\min \left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{|(a-1)^{n-1}+(a-1)^{n-2}a+..+a^{n-1}|}\right)$$

However, it strikes me that it might not be true, because inequality (1) might not hold when $a$ is negative.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your factoring notation, specifically where you have $a^{n-2}a$, since $a^{n-2}a = $a^{n-1}a$

Comment: @graydad you are right, I've just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that your inequality might not hold for lesser $x$, since the function $x\mapsto x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+x^{n-3}a^2+\ldots+a^{n-1}$ is only guarunteed to be increasing when $a$ and $x$ are positive. A much more important error you made is that you should be working with $(a+1)$ not $(a-1)$. In particular, your goal is to ensure that $|x^n-a^n|<\varepsilon$. Your reasoning at the moment is:

> Since $|x-a|\cdot |k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}a\ldots+a^{n-1}|<|x-a|\cdot |x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+\ldots +a^{n-1}|$ in the desired interval for some $k$, if we bound the *former* by $\varepsilon$, then the *latter* will also be bounded by $\varepsilon$.

This isn't good, because it's trying to say that if $A<B$ and $A<C$, then $B<C$ - which you should see the issue with. What you *want* to do is to say:

> Since $|x-a|\cdot |x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+\ldots +a^{n-1}|<|x-a|\cdot |k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}a\ldots+a^{n-1}|$ in the desired interval for some $k$, if we bound the *latter* by $\varepsilon$, then the *former* will also be bounded by $\varepsilon$.

which holds if you let $k=(a+1)$ and then $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{(a+1)^{n-1}+(a+1)^{n-2}a+\ldots+a^{n-1}})$. This, of course, only works when $x\geq 0$, but the argument for negative $x$ is fairly obvious from there (since $x^n$ is either an even or odd function)

Comment: thanks for help, that's a big issue you've mentioned. I'm still little confused about your even function or odd function comment. How should I make the inequality holds for all $a$ and $x$ ?

Comment: The even/odd thing is to notice that $|x^n-a^n|=|(-x)^n-(-a)^n|$ - meaning negative numbers act basically the same as positives. The point there is just that, for negative numbers, you'd actually want to look at $(a-1)$ instead of $(a+1)$. You could also do something like using $(2a)$ instead of either of those (and then $\min(a,\frac{\varepsilon}{\text{stuff}})$ instead of the minimum with $1$) - essentially you just want a number which is further from $0$ than $a$ is.

Comment: So, I'm thinking to make $|x-a|<a$. In this case, we get $0<x<2a$. So it guarantees that $x$, and $a$ is greater than 0. And the inequality holds. However, I do have a very weird feeling. forgive me that I'm not very familiar with $\epsilon,\delta$ things. My feeling is that, we have restricted $a$ is greater than 0. what if in a real question the $a$ is negative, then we are taking $\delta$ a negetive number, which is impossible

Comment: If $2a$ were negative, $\delta$ would still be positive - recall that we're not restricting $x$ to the range $0<x<2a$, rather, we're saying that we'll choose some $k$ (which we happen to take as $2a$) such that the ratio $\frac{|k^n-a^n|}{|k-a|}$ is larger than it would be anywhere near $a$, and use that to figure out some interval about $a$ where the difference is not too great. It happens that $|k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}a+k^{n-3}a^2+\ldots+a^{n-1}|$ is positive no matter what, and so is $\varepsilon$, so the quotient thereof, which is $\delta$ is still positive.

Comment: I actually come up with another proof. Could you check if this is rigorous? 


$$|x-a|\cdot|x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+...+xa^{n-2}+a^{n-1}| \leq |x-a| \left(|x^{n-1}|+|x^{n-2}|\cdot|a| +...+ |x|\cdot|a^{n-2}|+|a^{n-1}| \right)  $$. We actually can say that $$|x^{n}|=|x|^{n}$$



make $|x-a|<1$, $ |x|=|x-a+a| \leq |x-a|+|a| < 1+|a|$. We have $|x|^{k} < (1+|a|)^{k}$. we replace the latter one to the above inequality. we have $$|x^n-a^n| < |x-a|\cdot \left((1+|a|)^{n-1}|+|(1+|a|)^{n-2}|\cdot|a| +...+ |(1+|a|)|\cdot|a^{n-2}|+|a^{n-1}| \right) $$. Then we have our $\delta$

Comment: Yeah, that proof works well. (I quite like how you are using of absolute values; it's clever)